# Linux - Splitting a long line in a file into multiple lines based on a pattern

Tags: linux, parsing, awk, sed

I have a file with only one line which is a long string as below:

```
1. null  : null : I want to be line1 null  : null : I want to be line2
```

How can I split this line into multiple lines such that I get a file containing the following lines:

```
1.I want to be line1
2.I want to be line2
....
```

Comment: Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Comment: is there always `null  : null :` between intended lines? Or could be something else?

Comment: You have to be more precise than this. An answer solving your specific question is almost certainly not applicable to your real input. Is it colon separated? Or do you want every non-null string on its own line? Why is there no colon after `line1`? Why is the space between `line` and `2` gone in the output? Etc. etc. Also, you should show what you've tried and how it failed; otherwise, this is just a request for somebody else to *do* your work, not *help* you with it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, it is always " null  : null : "

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your feedback. In my case, the delimiter is the string " null : null: ". So, not colon separated. This answers your first three questions. Space between "line" and "2" is not supposed to disappear in the output. That was my typing error. I have edited my question to correct this. And I will update the question with what I have tried. I am certainly not asking someone to do the work for me. I am asking the question after spending some time trying it on my own. Perhaps, I was not specific enough, that's all !!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll give some help ... with ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F" *null *: null : *" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print i-1"."$i}' inputfile
```

The output:

```
1.I want to be line1
2.I want to be line2
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="null *: *null *: *" 'NR>1{print NR-1"."$0}' <<< "1. null  : null : I want to be line1 null  : null : I want to be line2"
1.I want to be line1 
2.I want to be line2
```

With perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(null *: *null *: *)(.*?)/\2\n/g' <<< "1. null  : null : I want to be line1 null  : null : I want to be line2" |tail -n+2 |nl -nln -w1 -s.
1.I want to be line1 
2.I want to be line2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'null  : null : ' '{print NR"." $2;print NR+1"."$3}' file

1.I want to be line1 
2.I want to be line2
```